# send cookies from quasar ssr to laravel backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, axios, server-side-rendering

I am building a web app using [Quasar SSR](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/introduction) for the front-end and [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) for the backend.

For Authentication, I use the new [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum) Package which uses cookies for user authentication.

Building the app in SPA, I have no problem to authenticate users. Unfortunately in SSR mode, no cookies are sent to the server thus making user authentication impossible.

I use axios to handle ajax request. I set it in a boot file.

Can someone help me send the cookies to the backend?

Editing to add some precisions. I am using nginx as a web server and my configuration is as follow:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/certs/www.mysite/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/certs/www.mysite/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    root /var/www/next/mysite/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name next.mysite.net;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    proxy_pass    http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /storage/ {
    }
    location /vendor/ {
    }
    location /server {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /prequel-api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /graphql {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /sanctum {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        #try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        #if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        #   return 404;
        #}

        # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        # include the fastcgi_param setting
        include fastcgi_params;

        # SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter is used for PHP FPM determining
        #  the script name. If it is not set in fastcgi_params file,
        # i.e. /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params or in the parent contexts,
        # please comment off following line:
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { boot } from "quasar/wrappers";
import { Cookies } from "quasar";
const axios = Axios.create({
 baseUrl: "https://next.mysite.net"
});
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response.data;
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error.response);
  }
);
export default boot(async ({ Vue, ssrContext }) => {
  if (process.env.SERVER) {
    //Check if cookies are available
    var cookies = JSON.stringify(Cookies.parseSSR(ssrContext).getAll()).replace(
      /[{}]/g,
      ""
    );
    console.log("cookies: ", cookies);
  }

  Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;
});

export { axios };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by extending the axios instance with cookies when creating the instance

//boot/axios.js (inside callback function)

```
if (ssrContext) {
    const cookies = ssrContext.$q.cookies.getAll();

    instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
      const cookiesSet = Object.keys(cookies).
        reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr + '=' + cookies[curr] + ';', '');

      if (cookiesSet.length > 0) {
        config.headers.Cookie = cookiesSet;
      }

      return config;
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution to attach the cookies. This is attaching all the available cookies already present on the client/browser. But the set-cookie header that is received from the /sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint is not getting attached to subsequent request(s). Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

the example above will work but it will add a callback element on every call which will cause performance loss and memory leak, I would add a check that the handler only added once